# Cant decide how will i import a module i created

Tags: python-3.x, class, import

I have created 2 python programs. One is a GUI and the other is the fuctions that should be done when a button is pressed in the gui. I got it working by using import XXXX when the button is pressed,seems ok but not pythonic. The teacher asked me to change the code.
 The first code is GUI.py and the second one is the module.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

from sys import exit
import os

class GUI:
   def __init__(self,root):

   ####### Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
    windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
    windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()

    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
    positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
   ##########----------------------


    root.title("Αρχική είσοδος")
    self.maingui=tk.Frame(root)
    self.maingui.pack()
    self.Label1=tk.Label(self.maingui,text="Καλώς ορίσατε στο βοήθημα γραμμικής άλγεβρας")
    self.Label1.pack()
    self.Label2=tk.Label(self.maingui,text="Παρακαλώ,διάλεξε μία από τις επιλογές")
    self.Label2.pack()
            ##
    self.sum_button=tk.Button(self.maingui,text="Πρόσθεση",command=self.sum_py)
    self.sum_button.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
            ##
    self.afairesh_button=tk.Button(self.maingui,text="Αφαίρεση",command=self.afairesi_py)
    self.afairesh_button.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
            ##
    self.pollaplasiasmos_button=tk.Button(self.maingui,text="Πολλαπλασιαμός Πίνακα",command=self.pollaplasiamos_py)
    self.pollaplasiasmos_button.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
            ##
    self.quit_button=tk.Button(self.maingui,text="Έξοδος",command=self.popupmsg)
    self.quit_button.pack(fill="both",expand=1)

def centered(self):
    # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
    windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
    windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
    print("Width",windowWidth,"Height",windowHeight)
    # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
    positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
    positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
    # Positions the window in the center of the page.
    root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

def kill(self):
    self.centered()
    root.destroy()
    popup.destroy()
    exit(0)

def sum_py(self):
    root.withdraw()
    import prosthesi

def afairesi_py(self):
    root.withdraw()
    import afairesh

def pollaplasiamos_py(self):
    root.withdraw()
    import pollaplasiasmos

def popupmsg(self):
    global popup
    root.withdraw()
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.title("Εξοδος")
    popup.iconbitmap('warn_img.ico')
    popup.geometry("200x100")
    warn = tk.Label(popup, text="Έξοδος?",)
    warn.pack()
    Yes= tk.Button(popup,text="Ναί",command =self.kill)
    Yes.pack()
    No= tk.Button(popup,text="Όχι",command = self.switch)
    No.pack()
    popup.resizable(0,0)
    popup.mainloop()

def switch(self):
    popup.destroy()  
    root.deiconify()  



   #--------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=tk.Tk()
    guitest=GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Module that must be imported

```
        from tkinter import *
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import sys
    import GUI
    import subprocess 
    import importlib


    class MyApp:
        def __init__(self,root):
    ####### Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
            windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
            windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()

            # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
            positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
            positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
            # Positions the window in the center of the page.
            root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
    ##########----------------------
            root.title("Αφαίρεση πινάκων")
            root.iconbitmap("minus_ico.ico")
            root.resizable(False, False)
            self.root=Frame(root)
            self.root.pack()
            self.start()
            self.entries1=[]
            self.entries2=[]
            self.entry_list1=[]
            self.entry_list2=[]
            self.entry_list1_2=[]
            self.entry_list2_2=[]
            self.entr1=[]
            self.entr2=[]
            self.res=[]       
        def start(self):
            self.label1=Label(self.root,text="Αφαίρεση πινάκων παραδείγματα",font="Arial 12")
            self.label1.grid(row=1,column=1)
            self.label2=Label(self.root,text="Διάλεξε τις διαστάσεις του πρώτου πίνακα",font="Arial 12")
            self.label2.grid(row=2,column=1)
            self.s1=Label(self.root,text="X:",font="Arial 10")
            self.entry1=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
            self.entry1.grid(row=3,column=1)
            self.s2=Label(self.root,text="Y:",font="Arial 10")
            self.s2.grid(row=4,column=1)
            self.entry2=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
            self.entry2.grid(row=4,column=1)
            self.w2=Label(self.root,text="Διάλεξε τις διαστάσεις του δεύτερου πίνακα",font="Arial 12")
            self.w2.grid(row=5,column=1)
            self.s3=Label(self.root,text="X:",font="Arial 10")
            self.s3.grid(row=6,column=1)
            self.entry3=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
            self.entry3.grid(row=6,column=1)
            self.s4=Label(self.root,text="Y:",font="Arial 10")
            self.s4.grid(row=7,column=1)
            self.entry4=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
            self.entry4.grid(row=7,column=1)
            self.w3=Button(self.root,text="Σχηματισμός πινάκων ",font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",command=self.multi)
            self.w3.grid(row=8,column=1)

            self.returnbutton=Button(self.root,text="Αρχική",bg="#d9d9d9",command=self.hide_and_return)
            self.returnbutton.grid(ipadx=0,ipady=0,row=8)
        def check(self):
            num="0123456789"
            self.entry1_value=self.entry1.get()
            self.entry2_value=self.entry2.get()
            self.entry3_value=self.entry3.get()
            self.entry4_value=self.entry4.get()
            if self.entry1_value not in num or self.entry2_value not in num or self.entry3_value not in num or self.entry4_value not in num:
                root.withdraw()
                alertwindow=Toplevel()
                alertwindow.title("Προσοχή")
                alertlabel=Label(alertwindow,text="Παρακαλώ,βάλε μόνο ακαίρεους αριθμούς!")
                alertlabel.pack()
                alertbutton=Button(alertwindow,text="Ξαναπροσπάθησε",command=self.restart)
                alertbutton.pack()              
            elif self.entry1_value=="" or self.entry2_value=="" or self.entry3_value=="" or self.entry4_value=="":
                root.withdraw()
                empty_alertwindow=Toplevel()
                empty_alertwindow.title("Προσοχή")
                empty_alertlabel=Label(empty_alertwindow,text="Παρακαλω,συμπλήρωσε ολα τα πεδία")
                empty_alertlabel.pack()
                empty_alertbutton=Button(empty_alertwindow,text="Ξαναπροσπάθησε",command=self.restart)
                empty_alertbutton.pack()
            if self.entry1_value!=self.entry3_value or self.entry2_value!=self.entry4_value:
                self.answer=Label(self.root,text="Δεν μπορείς να προσθέσεις πίνακες διαφορετικών διαστάσεων",font="Arial 15")
                self.answer.grid(row=9,column=1)
                self.clear=Button(self.root,text="Ξαναπροσπάθησε",font="Arial 12",command=self.restart)
                self.clear.grid(row=11,column=1)     
            else:
                self.creation()
        def creation(self):
            global q
            entry1_value=self.entry1.get()
            entry2_value=self.entry2.get()
            entry3_value=self.entry3.get()
            entry4_value=self.entry4.get()
            entry1_value=int(entry1_value)
            entry2_value=int(entry2_value)

            d=entry1_value*entry2_value
            s=Label(self.root,text="1ος πίνακας:",font="Arial 15")
            s.grid(row=12,column=1)
            for i in range(entry1_value):
                for w in range(entry2_value):
                    entry=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
                    entry.grid(row=12+i,column=2+w)
                    self.entries1.append(entry)
            s=Label(self.root,text="2ος πίνακας:",font="Arial 15")
            s.grid(row=15+entry1_value,column=1)
            for i in range(entry1_value):
                for w in range(entry2_value):
                    entry=Entry(self.root,font="Arial 12",bg="#d9d9d9",width=5)
                    entry.grid(row=15+entry1_value+i,column=2+w)
                    self.entries2.append(entry)

            q=Button(self.root,text="Αποτέλεσμα",font="Arial 14",state='active',command=self.result_lock)
            q.grid(row=16+2*entry1_value,column=1)

            false_button=Button(self.root,text="Έκανα λάθος",font="Arial 14",command=self.refresh)
            false_button.grid(row=16+2*entry1_value,ipadx=0,ipady=0)
        def result(self):
            entry1_value=self.entry1.get()
            entry2_value=self.entry2.get()
            entry3_value=self.entry3.get()
            entry4_value=self.entry4.get()
            entry1_value=int(entry1_value)
            entry2_value=int(entry2_value)
            d=entry1_value*entry2_value
            for x in self.entries1:
                res1=x.get()
                res1=int(res1)
                self.entry_list1.append(res1)
            for t in self.entries2:
                res2=t.get()
                res2=int(res2)
                self.entry_list2.append(res2)
            entry_count1=0
            for i in range(entry1_value):
                self.entry_list1_2.append(list(self.entry_list1[entry_count1:entry_count1+entry2_value]))
                self.entry_list2_2.append(list(self.entry_list2[entry_count1:entry_count1+entry2_value]))
                entry_count1+=entry2_value
            for x in self.entry_list1_2:
                for i in range(entry2_value):
                    self.entr1.append(x[i])
            for y in self.entry_list2_2:
                for i in range(entry2_value):
                    self.entr2.append(y[i])
            r=Label(self.root,text="Εδώ είναι αναλυτικά οι πράξεις:",font="Arial 12")
            r.grid(row=20+2*entry1_value,column=1)
            for c in range(d):
                self.res.append(self.entr1[c]-self.entr2[c])
            entry_count2=0   
            for t in range(entry1_value):
                for i in range(entry2_value):
                    f=Label(self.root,text="{}-{}={}".format(self.entr1[entry_count2],self.entr2[entry_count2],self.res[entry_count2]),font="Arial 12")
                    f.grid(row=20+2*entry1_value+t,column=2+i)
                    entry_count2+=1       
            e=Label(self.root,text="Ο πίνακας που προκύπτει είναι:",font="Arial 12")
            e.grid(row=25+2*entry1_value+d,column=1)
            entry_count3=0
            for t in range(entry1_value):
                for i in range(entry2_value):
                    e=Label(self.root,text="{}".format(self.res[entry_count3]),font="Arial 12")
                    e.grid(row=25+2*entry1_value+d+t,column=2+i)
                    entry_count3+=1
            g=Button(self.root,text="Ξαναπροσπάθησε",font="Arial 12",command=self.refresh)
            g.grid(row=28+2*entry1_value+d+entry1_value,column=1)

        def refresh(self):
            self.root.destroy()
            myapp=MyApp(root)

        def restart(self,):
            python = sys.executable
            os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

        def multi(self):
            self.check()
            self.w3['state']=DISABLED

        def result_lock(self):
             self.result()
             q.configure(state="disabled")

        def hide_and_return(self):
            root.withdraw()
            subprocess.Popen('GUI.py', shell=True)






    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    root=Tk()
    myapp=MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

My head is in the bottom of the files,with the root=tk() etc.. I am currently reading about the **init** function deeper,as suggested by my teacher. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your module is in the same folder as your main code file, you can just import using

```
import YourModule
```

this way you'll have all the functions and variables you need.

Comment: Hello!, by doing that the code would automatically run before the GUI.Thats why i am changing my solution